# Removing predictors from input to cor in R

Tags: r

I am using the Auto data set found [here](https://www.statlearning.com/resources-second-edition).

I am trying to call the cor function with a certain predictor excluded (the last one). I can achieve this by executing cor(Auto[,1:8]). This omits the ninth predictor.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? It would be nice to omit the predictor by name.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the `str(df)`, `horsepower` and `name` are characters (chr) which cannot be used for `cor` calculation. So, I have removed those two columns by column names like

```
df <- read.csv("Auto.csv")
head(df, 2)
str(df)

#> 'data.frame':    397 obs. of  9 variables:
#>  $ mpg         : num  18 15 18 16 17 15 14 14 14 15 ...
#>  $ cylinders   : int  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
#>  $ displacement: num  307 350 318 304 302 429 454 440 455 390 ...
#>  $ horsepower  : chr  "130" "165" "150" "150" ...
#>  $ weight      : int  3504 3693 3436 3433 3449 4341 4354 4312 4425 3850 ...
#>  $ acceleration: num  12 11.5 11 12 10.5 10 9 8.5 10 8.5 ...
#>  $ year        : int  70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
#>  $ origin      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ name        : chr  "chevrolet chevelle malibu" "buick skylark 320" "plymouth satellite" "amc rebel sst" ...

cor(df[!names(df) %in% c("horsepower", "name")])

#>                      mpg  cylinders displacement     weight acceleration       year     origin
#>  mpg           1.0000000 -0.7762599   -0.8044430 -0.8317389    0.4222974  0.5814695  0.5636979
#>  cylinders    -0.7762599  1.0000000    0.9509199  0.8970169   -0.5040606 -0.3467172 -0.5649716
#>  displacement -0.8044430  0.9509199    1.0000000  0.9331044   -0.5441618 -0.3698041 -0.6106643
#>  weight       -0.8317389  0.8970169    0.9331044  1.0000000   -0.4195023 -0.3079004 -0.5812652
#>  acceleration  0.4222974 -0.5040606   -0.5441618 -0.4195023    1.0000000  0.2829009  0.2100836
#>  year          0.5814695 -0.3467172   -0.3698041 -0.3079004    0.2829009  1.0000000  0.1843141
#>  origin        0.5636979 -0.5649716   -0.6106643 -0.5812652    0.2100836  0.1843141  1.0000000
```